# How to write an .mlp file (meshlab project) in C++?

Tags: c++, meshlab

I'm currently trying to open a .mlp project with meshlab which is created/ written out of an c++ program (all files e.g. mesh, texture and the .mlp are in the same folder).

I'm writing the .mlp project in following way:

```
wofstream myfile;
if (myfile.is_open())
    {
            myfile << L"<!DOCTYPE MeshLabDocument>\n<MeshLabProject>\n <MeshGroup>\n";
            //[...]
            myfile.close();

    }
```

The problem is: the final file can't be opened by meshlab or it is opened but not correctly: is shows that my mesh is loaded but there is no mesh/ a mesh with 0 vertices.

To check for mistakes, I created a sample project in meshlab and compared the resulting .mlp file to my in c++ created .mlp file: they booth look identical (only the values of the rotation/ translation matrices are slightly different).

The file size differs by some byte (between 10 and 18), so I added a bit of code (found [here](https://sockbandit.wordpress.com/2012/05/31/c-read-and-write-utf-8-file-using-standard-libarary/)) to get the encoding to UTF8:

```
myfile.imbue(std::locale(std::locale::empty(), new std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t, 0x10ffff, std::generate_header>));
```

Unfortunately this didn't fix the problem and meshlab is still unable to read my project...

If anyone has some tips or even a solution to this problem, I would be really grateful!

---

---

In addition:
Not-working .mlp looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE MeshLabDocument>
<MeshLabProject>
 <MeshGroup>
  <MLMesh filename="MeshedReconstruction1.ply" label="MeshedReconstruction1.ply">
   <MLMatrix44>
1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1
</MLMatrix44>
  </MLMesh>
 </MeshGroup>
 <RasterGroup>
  <MLRaster label="examplePic1.png">
   <VCGCamera RotationMatrix="0.999985 -0.005109 0.002027 0.000000 0.005126 0.999953 -0.008233 0.000000 -0.001985 0.008243 0.999964 0.000000 0 0 0 1" CenterPx="960 540" ViewportPx="1920 1080" TranslationVector="0.005810 -0.001382 -0.001205 1.000000" FocalMm="36.653561" LensDistortion="0 0" PixelSizeMm="0.0319256 0.0319256" CameraType="0"/>
   <Plane semantic="1" fileName="examplePic1.png"/>
  </MLRaster>
 </RasterGroup>
</MeshLabProject>
```

Working .mlp looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE MeshLabDocument>
<MeshLabProject>
 <MeshGroup>
  <MLMesh filename="MeshedReconstruction1.ply" label="MeshedReconstruction1.ply">
   <MLMatrix44>
1 0 0 0 
0 1 0 0 
0 0 1 0 
0 0 0 1 
</MLMatrix44>
  </MLMesh>
 </MeshGroup>
 <RasterGroup>
  <MLRaster label="examplePic1.png">
   <VCGCamera RotationMatrix="0.999683 0.0245459 0.00566618 0 -0.0245495 0.999699 0.000560548 0 -0.00565071 -0.000699472 0.999984 0 0 0 0 1 " CenterPx="960 540" ViewportPx="1920 1080" TranslationVector="-0.0273756 0.00583069 -0.398988 1" FocalMm="46.0408" LensDistortion="0 0" PixelSizeMm="0.0317889 0.0317889" CameraType="0"/>
   <Plane semantic="1" fileName="examplePic1.png"/>
  </MLRaster>
 </RasterGroup>
</MeshLabProject>
```

Comment: And if you make a `diff` between the working and non-working files, what do you get from that? Are there any differences?

Comment: What do you mean with `diff`? If it is the unix command: I'm using windows because I have to work with KinectFusion...

Comment: The term "diff" is generic and is used for all platforms for programs that compares files or lists differences between files. On Unix systems there is indeed a `diff` command, on Windows you have [the `fc` (File Compare) command](https://www.howtogeek.com/206123/how-to-use-fc-file-compare-from-the-windows-command-prompt/). There are also many graphical "diff" programs that easily can list the compared files side by side.

Comment: Because I didn't get the `fc` to work, I used mingw and got the following (with the not working file first and the working file second):
1,19c1,19
I'm not sure how to interpret this, even after I read [this](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/udiff.htm)

Comment: Besides `1,19c1,19` the `diff` command will then show you the data. I really suggest you look for a GUI diff tool.

Comment: However, the file you claim works have trailing spaces after the values in the `MLMatrix44` tag, and almost all values in the `VCGCamera` tag are different from yours. That's about it. Perhaps it's the `VCGCamera` values that are invalid in your file?

Comment: That's what I thought so too first, so I copied these values in the working file and they worked. Of course, the rotation/ translation differed by some degrees but it did work. And what kind of trailing spaces does appear after the lines as the `MLMatrix44`? In my non working file, I finished each line with a `\n` the code for that looks like this: `myfile << L"1 0 0 0\n0 1 0 0\n0 0 1 0\n0 0 0 1\n";`